# Google Analytics API returning only 10 rows

Tags: php, google-analytics

I am using this class to extract data from  Google Analytics:

https://github.com/erebusnz/gapi-google-analytics-php-interface

I am getting only 10 rows to display but I have more than 10 rows in my analytics data.

I have also set `max_results=50`. Still its showing only 10 rows.

Here is a screenshot showing more than 10 rows:

[image]

```
$start_date='2016-08-06';
$end_date='2016-09-05';
try {
      $ga->requestReportData(xxxxxxxx,
      array('browser'),
      array('pageviews'),
      $sort_metric=null, $filter=null,
      $start_date,$end_date,
      $start_index=1, $max_results=50);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
    }
    ?>
    <table width='60%'>
    <tr style="background-color:#00ff00;">
      <th>Browser</th>
      <th>Page Views</th>
    </tr>
    <?php
    foreach($ga->getResults() as $result):
    ?>
    <tr style="background-color:<?php echo $color ?>">
      <td><?php echo $result ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $result->getPageviews() ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
    endforeach
    ?>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with you that your code looks correct however I wonder if the screenshot you attached represents the same date range as the code is looking at. If your Google Analytics view which you provided a screenshot of is covering a longer period than the code is retrieving it seems plausible considering the relatively low volume of sessions for items 11 through 16 that you're not retrieving that data because it falls outside of the date range you're requesting data on. What happens if you open that date range up to, say, a year?

```
$start_date='2015-08-06';
$end_date='2016-09-05';
try {
      $ga->requestReportData(xxxxxxxx,
      array('browser'),
      array('pageviews'),
      $sort_metric=null, $filter=null,
      $start_date,$end_date,
      $start_index=1, $max_results=50);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
    }
    ?>
    <table width='60%'>
    <tr style="background-color:#00ff00;">
      <th>Browser</th>
      <th>Page Views</th>
    </tr>
    <?php
    foreach($ga->getResults() as $result):
    ?>
    <tr style="background-color:<?php echo $color ?>">
      <td><?php echo $result ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $result->getPageviews() ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
    endforeach
    ?>
    </table>
```

In your original code you are requesting data starting from Today and extending through September 5th of this year, meaning the only values you retrieve would relate to sessions that occurred today. Odds are high that nobody visited your site today using YE, SeaMonkey, Maxthon, Amazon Silk, Opera Mini, or UC Browser. Everything above those six represent more common usage patterns likely to have visited today.

Comment: if i compare results from 6july2015 to 5 August 2016, then google control panel shows me 37 results. But the api shows me 28 results. where are the missing rows.

Comment: instead of september i tried now with 5th august, and again i am not receiving all data. 9 rows are again missing

Comment: @vineet again I will ask, what time period does the screenshot you provided from Google Analytics represent?

Comment: the screenshot is of 6july2016 to 5august 2016

Comment: Have you confirmed that the date format is correct? Is it YYYY-MM-DD or YYYY-DD-MM?

Comment: 5august2016 is the last date that google allowed me to select.

Comment: @vineet correct, that is yesterday. My question before remains.

Comment: if the date format was wrong then it should not have displayed any row. if its displaying some rows that means date format is correct

Comment: That would depend on how new your analytics account is and how far back Google keeps records accessible. 08, 06, 09, and 05 are all numbers less than 12 which means they are valid as entries for both months and days.

Comment: this time i tried $start_date='2016-07-01';
$end_date='2016-08-01'; means 1july2016 to 1august2016. according to these dates google returns 15 rows but the api returns only 6. dont know where are these rows going missing.

Comment: What happens if you try 2016-01-08 and 2016-01-07?

Comment: with start_date 2016-01-08 and end date 2016-01-07 it gives error Caught exception: GAPI: Failed to request report data. Error: "Invalid Date Range: end-date 2016-01-07 precedes start-date 2016-01-08" .

Comment: if i write 2016-01-07 and end date as 2016-01-08 then google shows 12 rows and api shows 3 rows.

Comment: Try adding the 'includeEmptyRows' parameter?

Comment: @vineet you swapped them, I'm saying swap the month and date places

Comment: @Matt where should i add includeEmptyRows Parameter. How should i include this parameter

Comment: @JBartus if i write 2016-07-01 to 2016-08-01 then also i dont get all rows

Comment: @JBartus i just tried it in query explorer https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?ids=ga%3Axxxxxxxx&start-date=2016-07-01&end-date=2016-08-01&metrics=ga%3Apageviews&dimensions=ga%3Abrowser&max-results=30, it showed me all 15 results